# Url rewrite difficulty

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

What I want to achieve is, if direct path doesn't exist then rewrite to index.php. Here is how it looks in apache syntax

```
# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d



# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL

RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

My nginx conf looks like that:

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$uri?$args;
}
```

But it looks for file, if doesn't exist returns error file not found. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you facing problem with nginx or apache?

Comment: @RahilWazir I'm trying to achieve this in nginx configuration

Comment: Try this /index.php?$query_string; in your target.

Comment: did you set the `root` correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?req=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I need to convert this into nginx:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1;
}
```